# MPLabX IDE Linker error with X32 compiler

Tags: c++, ide, mplab

I am using pic32 device for my c++ project.

While compiling i got the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc32\v1.30\bin\xc32-g++.exe"
     -mprocessor=32MZ2048ECM144  
     -o dist/default/production/DF.X.production.elf 
     build/default/production/_ext/1323855441/newfile.o
     H:\GUI\simulation\C-CODE\vsss\Debug\wavelet2d.lib
     -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1\
        ,--script="H:\GUI\simulation\C-CODE\vsss\Debug\wavelet2d.lib"\
        ,-Map="dist/default/production/DF.X.production.map"
c:/program files (x86)/microchip/xc32/v1.30/bin/../lib/gcc/pic32mx/4.5.2/../../../../pic32mx/bin/ld.exe:H:\GUI\simulation\C-CODE\vsss\Debug\wavelet2d.lib:1:syntax error 
collect2: ld returned 1 
exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/DF.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/sony/MPLABXProjects/DF.X'
make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/sony/MPLABXProjects/DF.X' 
BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 208ms)
```

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>

#include "F:\MTECH-PROJECT\simulation\C-CODE\wavelet-lib\wavelib\src\shared\wavelet2d.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>

inline double round(double x){
    return (floor(x+0.5));
}

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    //cout << "Enter the name of signal file at the Prompt eg., signal.txt :" << endl;
    char inp[200000]="H:\\GUI\\simulation\\C-CODE\\vsss\\signal.txt";//voltage
    char inp1[200000]="H:\\GUI\\simulation\\C-CODE\\vsss\\vsag.txt";//voltage sag
    //cin >> inp;

    string nm="db10";
    vector<double> sig;
    vector<double> vsag;

    ifstream sig_inp(inp);
    if ( !sig_inp.good()){
        //cout << "The File doesn’t exist"<< endl;
    }
    while (!sig_inp.eof()) {
        double temp1;
        sig_inp >> temp1;
        sig.push_back(temp1);
    }
    sig.pop_back();
    vector<double> original;
    original = sig;

    ifstream vsag_inp1(inp1);
    if ( !vsag_inp1.good()){
        //cout << "The File doesn’t exist"<< endl;
    }
    while (!vsag_inp1.eof()) {
        double temp;
        vsag_inp1 >> temp;
        vsag.push_back(temp);
    }
    vsag.pop_back();
    vector<double> original1;
    original1 = vsag;

    //cout << "Please Enter the Number of DWT Stages J :" << endl;
    int J=6,s;

    getch();
    vector<double> dwt_output, flag;
    // perform J-Level DWT
    vector<int> length;
    dwt_sym(vsag, J, nm, dwt_output,flag,length);
    ofstream dwtout("C:\\Users\\sony\\Desktop\\PROJECT\\dwtout.txt",ios::out);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < dwt_output.size(); i++){
        dwtout << dwt_output[i] << endl;
    }

    //Perform J-Level IDWT
    vector<double> output;
    double q[1200],q1[1200];
    idwt_sym(dwt_output, flag,nm,output,length);
    ofstream sig2("G:\\GUI\\FILES\\recon.txt");
    ofstream diff("G:\\GUI\\FILES\\diff.txt");
    //cout <<" Recon signal size" << output.size() << endl;
    s=original.size();
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        q[i]=original[i]- output[i];
        sig2 << output[i] << endl;
        diff <<original[i]- output[i] << endl;
    }
    double q2[1200],qs[1200];
    ofstream diff1("G:\\GUI\\FILES\\diff1.txt");

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        qs[i]=original[i]- output[i];
        //cout<<original[i]<<"\t"<<output[i]<<"\t"<<q[i]<<"\n";
        diff1 << q[i]<<"\n";
    }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < s;i++){
        q1[i]=abs(q[i]);
        //cout<<q1[i];
        q2[i]=round(q1[i]);
    }
    //cout<<"round"<<q[1]<<"\t"<<round(q1[1]);
    int w;

    w=255;
    int j=1;
    int t1;

    while (j<w)
    {
        if ((q2[j]==0) && (q2[j+1]>1))
        {
            t1=j;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }

    int start_time;
    start_time=j+1;
    int t2;

    while (j<w)
    {
        if ((q2[j]>0) && (q2[j+1]==0) && (q2[j+1]==0) && (q2[j+2]==0)) {
            t2=j;
            break;
        }
        j++;
    }
    int end_time;
    end_time=j+1;
    int p;
    double max,q3[1200];
    //p=start_time;
    for (int i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        q3[i]=original1[i];
    }

    max=original[0];

    for (p=start_time;p<end_time;p++)
    {
        if (q3[p]>max)
            max=q3[p];
    }

    double magnitude;
    magnitude=abs(max);
    getch();
    cout<<"\n\n"<<"RESULTS OF ALGORITHM USING DISCRETE WAVELET TRANSFORM"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"*****************************************************"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Input signal:230V 50Hz single phase AC"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Voltage sag parameters"<<"\n\n";
    cout<<"Start time(ms):"<<start_time<<"\n"<<"End time(ms):"<<end_time<<"\n"<<"Magnitude(V):"<<magnitude<<"\n";
    //gnudwtplot(J);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please run your title through `tr [[:upper:]] [[:lower:]]`.

Comment: i think error points to linker file